# Firebase Deploy - Site Not Found (Stripe Project)

Tags: firebase, command-line-interface

I seem to be having issues getting my site live onto the Firebase Hosting.

I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe

Which has these steps:

- Create a Firebase Project using the Firebase Developer Console
- Enable billing on your project by switching to the Blaze or Flame plan. See pricing for more details. This is required to be able to do requests to non-Google services.
- Enable Google sign on your Firebase project
- Install Firebase CLI Tools if you have not already and log in with `firebase login`.

> RESULT: Already logged in as user@gmail.com

- Configure this sample to use your project using `firebase use --add` and select your project.

> RESULT: Error: Firebase use must be run from a Firebase Directory
>
> Run **firebase init** to start a project

- Run firebase init

> What Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this directory?
>   Database
>   Functions
>   Hosting

**I chose HOSTING.**

- Select a default Firebase project for this directory

**I Chose the only project there and got:**

```
✔ Firebase initialization complete
```

**I Ran Firebase use --add** again, chose and alias and not it says:

> Now using alias stageTemp.

- Install dependencies locally by running: `cd functions; npm install; cd -`

> npm WARN stripe-functions@ No repository field
>
> npm WARN stripe-functions@ No license field.

- Add your Stripe API Secret Key to firebase config: `firebase functions:config:set stripe.token=<YOUR STRIPE API KEY>`
- Optional: change your default currency `firebase functions:config:set stripe.currency=GBP`
- Pass your Stripe publishable key to the `Stripe.setPublishableKey` call in `public/index.html`
- Deploy your project using `firebase deploy`

When I run Firebase Deploy I get

```
    i  deploying functions
    i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
    i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
    ✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
    ✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
    i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
    i  functions: packaged functions (2.91 KB) for uploading
    ✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
    i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...
    i  functions: updating function createStripeCharge...
    i  functions: updating function createStripeCustomer...
    i  functions: updating function addPaymentSource...
    i  functions: updating function cleanupUser...
    ✔  functions[createStripeCharge]: Successful update operation. 
    ✔  functions[createStripeCustomer]: Successful update operation. 
    ✔  functions[addPaymentSource]: Successful update operation. 
    ✔  functions[cleanupUser]: Successful update operation. 
    ✔  functions: all functions deployed successfully!

    ✔  Deploy complete!
```

Finally:

- Test your Stripe integration by viewing your deployed site firebase open hosting:site

and then I get this:

[image]

Can anyone see why this is not working? I have gone through these steps several times and cannot seem to get it to work.

Much appreciated.

## Questions for Firebase Devs:

1) This code on the example has: `amount: parseInt()`. What checks are in place to make sure that the DOM is not simply edited by the user?

2) This process saves a lot of data. Is Firebase PCI Compliant so that I am legally allowed to store this data?

3) I'm confused about the process flow of functions. Is there an editable file that is run on the cloud where I can add extra information and database interactions or email sending? - I ask this because I want to insert into the database only when payment is verified. If I code it from the front end then a user could just run that in the console or wherever and insert into my db as it will have write access. (I hope this makes sense - I basically just want my function to be able to access the database and not anyone else)

Thank you for your time, I understand that you will be terrible busy and I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Your deploy log doesn't indicate anything about deploying hosting, but you're opening the hosting page. Is there a `{hosting: {public}}` in your `firebase.json`? Do you have a public dir?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thank you. From that specific doc there was nothing stating I needed to initiate a project first. All done and the sample is working. I noticed you work at firebase, I wonder if you could answer the 3 questions that I have added to the end of my original post? Thank you